# Pandas dataframe how to remove rows conditioned on the length of rows being smaller than a number, given a unique column value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks something like

```
     date        id      params 
123  2016-03-02  0A122B  23.7
124  2016-03-03  0A122B  25.5
125  2016-03-04  0A122B  29.7
126  2016-03-07  0A122B  26.4
... 
456  2016-03-02  3B778C  1050
457  2016-03-03  3B778C  1350
458  2016-03-04  3B778C  2900
...
1255 2016-03-02  5D898F  135.88
1256 2016-03-03  5D898F  189.55
1257 2016-03-04  5D898F  205.22
1258 2016-03-07  5D898F  278.35
1259 2016-03-08  5D898F  145.64
```

For a particular unique `id`, it has rows of `date` and also its `params`. Note that the length of amount of rows of `id` can be different. For example, `0A122B` may only have `date` data of length 48 and `5D898F` maybe instead data of length `1255`.

I'd like to know a way to remove rows of data **where for a particular `id` e.g.`0A122B` , its total amount of rows is less than a number, say 50, for each and everyone of the `id`.**

Comment: To clarify. You're looking to keep up to 50 (for example) entries for each `id`? or you're looking to remove all `id` groups with less than 50 (for example) entries?

Comment: For each `id`, if its total length of rows for dates is smaller/bigger than a number/percentage, then remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `groupby`:

```
output = df[df.groupby("id")["date"].transform("count")>50]
```